# Как поменять уникальный идентификатор

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Как поменять уникальный идентификатор.
Сейчас у меня id, а нужно, чтобы был только phone.

User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ApiTable", schema = "TestApi")
public class User {
    @Id
    private int id;

    private String phone;
    private String message;

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setLastName(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

UserRepo

```
public interface UserRepo extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

Comment: `@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)` а не это ли вам нужно было убрать?

Comment: Я убирал, а он ошибку выкидывает, которая в посте. Обновил ошибку.

Comment: `ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save():` не пробовали перед тем как вызывать `save` указывать id?

Comment: Обновил пост, добавил код с контроллером. Не пытался id указывать. А нужно? Извините, если вопрос глупый. БД проверил, Postman проверил, нигде не указываю, чтобы мне Id отправлялся. Может, это postman что-то не так делает? Посылаю такой запрос {
  "phone": "5443345",
  "message": "Hello World"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Теперь нашим идентификатором является phone, а не id.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ApiTable", schema = "TestApi")
public class User {

    @Id   
    private String phone;

    private String message;

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setLastName(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

И меняем репозиторий:

```
public interface UserRepo extends CrudRepository<User, String> {
}
```

Оригинал [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58639827/how-to-make-phone-as-id-spring-boot/58640313?noredirect=1#comment103589930_58640313).